# Hot to resolve a promise before service creation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

In angular (1.0.8) `$routeProvider` can resolve promises before it redirects to controller. I have a common functionality (in a service) that should be accessed from two different links. i can add the same resolve to two different paths in `$routeProvider`  but this is duplication. is there any way to resolve promises before a service is created?

Comment: So how do you use your service in controller. Can you simply make that the service return promise and also cache it's results so it resolves immediately after the first time?

Comment: not really. i need a result of the promise to compute initial state of the service, before returning that service

Comment: service is singleton. Do you mean for that 2 links, you need to resolve a promise and call some init function of that service?

Comment: when user enters my application i want my service to get id from  url, ask backend to get value for that id and store that value forever for all controllers

Answer (score 0):

As Mavlam said, services are singletons. Since you provided absolutely no code, then answer will not be accurate, but the concept will.

You can do something like this in your service:

```
this.userData = false;
return {
    init: function(id) {
        fetchStuffForTheUser(id).then(function(response) {
            this.userData = response;
        });
    },
    getUserData: function() {
        return userData;
    }
 }
```

`init` will fetch the user data and store it in `this.userData` for the whole session. After that, `getUserData` will always return that data for every controller you call it from.

Comment: but promise will **not** be resolved before service creation. therefore each controller using that service has to be aware that data might be missing

Comment: True, but you also can't call the service before it's created, can you? If you want to wait for init to happen, wait for the init promise(s) to resolve in module.run callback, and only launch the app once everything's ready.

Comment: @Jasper pretty much the same way as you do in the controllers. See if this simple example helps: http://jsfiddle.net/776p73x8/